# How to manage a DB query result set as group of objects?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been requested to manage entities stored in a DB as object once retrieved. My questione is related on when a `SELECT` returns many tuples. 
I'd need to use every result to create a new object, the problem is that off course I can't anticipate how many, and which name use on them.

**question improvement**:
However I already know the table structure, and I already have wrote the class to instatiate a single class, I'm just wondering on the correct way to manager an arbitrary numer of them.

My idea so far is to use an array, and push into it a new object for every row in the result set.

Please, your opinions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is vague. Having an object by itself is not of any value. This only makes sense if you have a specific type of object. Then your task would be to convert each entry in the result set into a separate object. There are solutions for this called ORMs (object relational mappers). But you need a definition of the object structure, so a class implementation for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
 public function getDataFromTable() 
{
$con = new mysqli(db_host, db_user,db_pass,db_name);
if ($con->connect_errno) {
    print ("Connection error (" . $con->connect_errno . "): $con->connect_error");
}
else {
    // $res is a result of this query down

    $res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM whatever");
    if ($res) 
    {
        $whatever=null;
        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()) //row will be one row from table and you just need to create your objects and put them in array, then return array.. ofc you will return this like json, and after that you will need to encode that and do something with response
        {
            $whatever[]=new Whatever($row["id"],$row["name"]);
        }
        $res->close();
        return $whatever;
    }
    else
    {
        print ("Query failed");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Be careful when u try to insert(delete) or something like that try to do with table, because then $res wont have a table, $res will be like boolean , true->correct query and false->incorrect query , and in that case you will not have this part $res->close() , cus that will be a error in that case!